# "Updating" a string with a format operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

This might be a very simple question, but I can't find an answer for it anywhere else online.
I have a variable that is set as a string with a %s format operator in it.

```
var1 = "Arbaham"
var2 = "My name is: %s" % var1
print(var2)
var1 = "Abraham"
print(var2)
```

Results in:

> My name is: Arbaham
>
> My name is: Arbaham

Is it possible to "update" the string so that it changes from "My name is: Arbaham" to "My name is: Abraham" on the second printing?

Comment: Did you mean to use a different name the second time? And the short answer is no, strings are immutable. You can create a new string and stick it in var2 `var2 = "My name is: %s" % var1` just like the first time, but the original string is not changed.

Comment: Yes you can, check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting

Comment: @personjerry how does a different formatting technique solve the problem?

Comment: @tdelaney The current problem is that he's hardcoded the variable into the string. With syntax like `"My name is {name}".format(name="hello")` we can preserve the string `"My name is {name}"`, but modifying the key `name` will let us replace with the updated name, thus solving the problem elegantly.

Comment: @personjerry but that's pretty much the same as preserving "My name is: %s". One might prefer one style to the other but it doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @tdelaney Oh I see, the problem was that he didn't save the string before replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the usage you want is to save the string before replacing the token:

```
var1 = "Arbaham"
var2 = "My name is: %s"
print(var2 % var1)
var1 = "Abraham"
print(var2 % var1)
```

Output:

```
>>> var1 = "Arbaham"
>>> var2 = "My name is: %s"
>>> print(var2 % var1)
My name is: Arbaham
>>> var1 = "Abraham"
>>> print(var2 % var1)
My name is: Abraham
```

Comment: All you did was change to a different formatting technique in python. The `%s` version works just as well. I still haven't figured out what the question is... and tried a comment to see if I could prod OP into a clarification.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is that once he changes `var1`, the `var2` string should be updated. I've updated my answer to address this, instead of using `str.format()`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, because this solution actually works just fine. Thanks to everyone anyway.